# save email, country, ..., full name from facebook to database with login with facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'myappid', 
    channelUrl : '//www.mywebsite.com/channel.html', 
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      // testAPI();

FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session == 'connected' && response.scope) {
        FB.api('/me',  function(response) {
            window.location = "http://www.mywebsite.com/checkloginfb.php?email=" + response.email;
          }
        );
      }
    } , {scope: 'email'}); 


    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      // FB.login();

FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session == 'connected' && response.scope) {
        FB.api('/me',  function(response) {
            window.location = "http://www.mywebsite.com/checkloginfb.php?email=" + response.email;
          }
        );
      }
    } , {scope: 'email'}); 

    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session == 'connected' && response.scope) {
        FB.api('/me',  function(response) {
            window.location = "http://www.mywebsite.com/checkloginfb.php?email=" + response.email;
          }
        );
      }
    } , {scope: 'email'}); 
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

I want to give my users the option to login with facebook, but I do not know why it does not work. I get infinitly popups. This is my first time doing this and I just can not understand me. I want to get the email, country, profile picture and full name of the user so I can add it to database.

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to login the user even if the user is already `connected`. This creates the infinite loop cycles.

```
// Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
  // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
  // have logged in to the app.
  // testAPI();

    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session == 'connected' && response.scope) {
        FB.api('/me',  function(response) {
            window.location = "http://www.mywebsite.com/checkloginfb.php?email=" + response.email;
          }
        );
      }
    } , {scope: 'email'}); 
}
```

I would recommend separating, `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(){}` from `FB.Login(function(){}, {})`.

The `auth.authResponseChange` will fire anytime the user's authentication status has changed, while the `FB.Login` attempts to get the user's permission and authorize the application etc.